# hide border of email input textbox

Tags: css

This is the default css and I cannot modify it.

```
#edd_checkout_form_wrap input.edd-input, #edd_checkout_form_wrap input[type=email], #edd_checkout_form_wrap input[type=password], #edd_checkout_form_wrap input[type=text], #edd_checkout_form_wrap textarea, #edd_checkout_form_wrap textarea.edd-input, .marketify-input, input[type=search], input[type=text], input[type=email], input[type=url], input[type=password], input[type=number], textarea {
    color: #404040;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    word-break: normal;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-siding: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I want to hide the border of email input
My css is

```
#edd-email {
    border: 0;
}
```

but it seems `input[type=email]` and `border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;`in default css is called soon later, so that the border is still there.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply, override with `!important`

```
 #edd-email {
    border: 0 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Remember that usage of `!important` is a bit risky, because it will always override your CSS. Use it carefully and never overuse it ;)

Comment: I know, but in this case the `!important` is a good solution because he wants to override a code that he can't modify.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has its own precedence

1. `!important`
2. Specificity Calculations

   1. Style Attribute
   2. ID
   3. Class, Pseudo-Class, Attribute
   4. elements
3. Inheritance
4. The Cascade

   So try targeting that specific element, if that doesnt work then use `!important` tag as last resort.